# NodeMediaServer: why are removed video chunk after stopping streaming:

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, rtmp, flash-media-server

I'm using node-media-server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server) for building a streaming application. I set the following configuration to save video data into a directory ./server/media

```
rtmp_server: {
    http: {
        port: 8888,
        mediaroot: './server/media',
    }
....
```

During streaming I see the chuncks of video streaming in the directory but, after stopping the live, these files are removed.

How can I avoid that these file are removed? Is there any configuration to set that?

Answer (score 0):

Thats part of the code in https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server/blob/master/node_trans_session.js
You have to delete these lines

```
fs.readdir(ouPath, function (err, files) {
    if (!err) {
      files.forEach((filename) => {
        if (filename.endsWith('.ts')
          || filename.endsWith('.m3u8')
          || filename.endsWith('.mpd')
          || filename.endsWith('.m4s')
          || filename.endsWith('.tmp')) {
          fs.unlinkSync(ouPath + '/' + filename);
        }
      })
    }
  });
```